# get querystring from URL regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, query-string

I am able to get the querystring from url like this using regex and javascript: But I need to get rid of these %22...these don't show up in IE, just in FF..How do I do that? Ineeed everything after k=..but without %22..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">document.write('<div class="DynamicSearchTitle">
Showing All Results For ' +  
location.href.match(/\&k\=(.+)/)[1]+ ' Matches </div>'); 
</script>
```

URL

http://mysite/sites/dev/contact-us/Pages/LocationSearchTestPage.aspx?s=bcs_locations&k=%22Hospital%22%20OR%20%22Office%22

Comment: URL doesn't work. "Page Not Found".

Comment: why would you need the URL to work? I just included sample URL..the real url is not live yet..

Comment: Stop using spaces and strange characters in your querystring and you should be golden?

Comment: I wish I could do that! Strange world of Sharepoint has weird ways to get things done :)

Comment: Note that you can extract the query string more conveniently using `location.search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is broken so I can't take a look at the whole code, but I think what you're looking for is the [decodeURI-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

```
decodeURI("%22")
```

for example would return "

Unescapeing the url from your question:

```
decodeURI("&k=%22Hospital%22%20OR%20%22Office%22");
```

returns `&k="Hospital" OR "Office"`

Comment: unescape is bad. It does not work for non-ASCII characters. -1 for w3schools reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the Query String component by simple JS function described [here](http://shiplu.mokadd.im/61/parse-query-string-by-pure-javascrirpt/)

Use it like this,

```
var uparts = getUrlParts(location.href);
var the_K = uparts["k"];
```